# SSRS Bar Chart Filtering Incorrectly

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to create a chart showing the 10 highest-performing teams according to their "proportion of target achieved" score.

My dataset comprises every day worked by every individual in my organisation. The data is grouped in a stored procedure by month, team, job role, area of the organisation...

My SSRS report takes this data and sums it at a report level, based on a half-dozen parameters (mainly to the above groups).

The data is presented via a table, showing (for a given person/group/category) the hours worked, actual contact time (time with clients), expected contact time (time they're meant to spend with clients), and the proportion of their target they are achieving (actual contact time / expected contact time). All of this is reported for each of the last 6 months.

I.e.

[image: Table of data]

I wanted to create a bar chart showing the 10 teams with the highest *proportion of target achieved* values. This variable is calculated in SSRS in order to allow for the data to be more flexible.

SSRS wouldn't let me use that calculation in a chart filter, so I added a denserank (called *TeamOrder*) for the teams in the stored procedure.

This is where the issue arises.

*TeamOrder* is used in the filter, and set to <= 10. 10 teams are displayed in the graph, but not the 10 that have values of *TeamOrder* equal to 1-10. The top couple are right, but in 10th position, for example, it's displaying the 32nd-best team.

Weirdly, when I set the filter to *TeamOrder* = [value], then it displays the one (correct) team (including the correct number 10 when *TeamOrder* = 10).

I'm at a complete loss as to what might be happening; any help would be enormously appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show `1.` A mockup of the data as it is returned from your dataset query and `2,` Your Chart design including the grouping/filtering etc

Comment: To troubleshoot, I would make a table with your TeamOrder, the chart value field, and any Category or Series fields to review the data that's going into the chart.